# DFP ads not working in my django website

Tags: django, google-dfp

I have created Ad units and generated tags for displaying the ads in my website from The DFP dashboard. It works fine when I simply make an html file with the code generated. But when I try to integrate the same code with my website, the ads are not rendering. When I checked in the google console it shows the iframe type to be none and for the simply html file, the iframe type is SafeFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my IP. When I run the django server on localhost instead of my IP, google ads got rendered.